# Count POS Tags by column

Tags: r, nlp, text-analysis

I am trying to count all Part-Of-Speech tags in a row and sum it up.

By now I reached two outputs:

1) The/DT question/NN was/VBD ,/, what/WP are/VBP you/PRP going/VBG to/TO cut/VB ?/.

2) c("DT", "NN", "VBD", ",", "WP", "VBP", "PRP", "VBG", "TO", "VB", ".")

In this particular example desirable output is:

```
        DT  NN  VBD  WP  VBP  PRP   VBG   TO   VB
1 doc   1   1    1   1    1    1     1     1    1
```

But since I want to create it for the whole column in dataframe I want to see there 0 values as well in a columns, which corresponds to a POS tag which was not used in this sentence.

Example:

```
1 doc = "The/DT question/NN was/VBD ,/, what/WP are/VBP you/PRP going/VBG to/TO cut/VB ?/" 

2 doc = "Response/NN ?/."
```

Output:

```
        DT  NN  VBD  WP  VBP  PRP   VBG   TO   VB
1 doc   1   1    1   1    1    1     1     1    1
2 doc   0   1    0   0    0    0     0     0    0
```

What I did by now:

```
library(stringr)
#Spliting into sentence based on carriage return

s <- unlist(lapply(df$sentence, function(x) { str_split(x, "\n")     }))

library(NLP)
library(openNLP)

tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
s <- as.String(x)
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
a3 <- annotate(s, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}

result <- lapply(s,tagPOS)
result <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,result))
```

That's how I reached the output which was described at the beginning

I have tried to count occurrences like this:
    occurrences<-as.data.frame (table(unlist(result$POStags)))

But it count occurrences through the whole dataframe. I need to create new column to existing dataframe and count occurrences in the first column.

Can anyone help me please? :(

Comment: well done on adding desired output and what you've tried so far, but could you also provide a sample of your `df`?

Comment: also maybe look into `tm::TermDocumentMatrix`, using your POStags in stead of the actual words in your documents to create the matrix.

Comment: I had the same idea regarding tm. I will try it later today. Thank you!

Regarding df: 
`The question was, what are you going to cut?
It's completely out of control.
I support clean coal technology.`

This is what I have in df

Comment: Each sentence — one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tm` is relatively painfree:

**dummy data**

```
require(tm)
   df <- data.frame(ID = c("doc1","doc2"), 
                    tags = c(paste("NN"), 
                             paste("DT", "NN", "VBD", ",", "WP",   "VBP", "PRP", "VBG", "TO", "VB", ".")))
```

**make corpus and DocumentTermMatrix:**

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$tags))
#default minimum wordlength is 3, so make sure you change this
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control= list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))

#see what you've done
inspect(dtm)

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 9)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 10/8
Sparsity           : 44%
Maximal term length: 3
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs dt nn prp to vb vbd vbg vbp wp
   1  0  1   0  0  0   0   0   0  0
   2  1  1   1  1  1   1   1   1  1
```

eta: if you dislike working with a dtm, you can coerce it to a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))

  nn dt prp to vb vbd vbg vbp wp
1  1  0   0  0  0   0   0   0  0
2  1  1   1  1  1   1   1   1  1
```

eta2: `Corpus` creates a corpus of column `df$tags` only, and `VectorSource` assumes that each row in the data is one document, so the order of rows in the dataframe `df`, and the order of documents in the `DocumentTermMatrix` are the same: i can `cbind` `df$ID` onto the output dataframe. I do this using `dplyr` because i think it results in the most readable code (read `%>%` as "and then") :

```
require(dplyr)
result <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm)) %>%
          bind_col(df$ID)
```

Comment: also see the edit if you are now thinking "what am i supposed to do with a `simple_triplet_matrix`??!"

Comment: there's also a control option somewhere that will you can set to not convert the POStag names to lowercase.

Comment: Yep, that's great! Thank you again!

Comment: One more question.
So I have tries on a small dataset and it worked fine but now I am trying for 2500 rows and I am a bit confused. Should I really specify all rows here `ID = c("doc1","doc2")`? But than it will be 2500. I have done it like this `ID = results$POSTags` but than the next problem — I have a lot of POSes as well.

Am I right that I have to write something like:
`df <- data.frame(ID = 1, 
                 tags = c(paste("DT", "NN", "VBD", ",", "WP",   "VBP", "PRP", "VBG", "TO", "VB", ".")))`, where inside paste() I have to specify all possible POS-tags?

Comment: Hm... Did in this way:
`df <- data.frame(ID = 1, tags = c(paste("DT", "NN", "VBD", ",", "WP", "VBP", "PRP", "VBG", "TO", "VB", ".")))` and it gave me 33 POS tags and processed all documents. Hm... I have no Idea how it worked but the data seems fine.

Can you please than tell me in few words what exactly this row does? If you have time of course. You already did a lot to me

Comment: if i understand your data correctly, then what i have as `df$tags` is your `result$POStags`. You shouldn't have to manually specify all rows and you don't have to specify all POStags, `DocumentTermMatrix` automatically determines which tags there are and fills the matrix accordingly.